# How to add other shapes in swimlane diagram in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I need to add shapes in swimlane diagram with some shapes that’s not in excel or PowerPoint shapes already to create swimlane diagram. Please see [image]attached picture. I want to add shapes in swimlane diagram for “note”, “manual process”, “links”. Could you please guide me what kind of [image]shapes I can use it for or is there a way to add custom shapes or are there any alternate shapes already in excel->insert->shapes?